# How to check if there is internet connection in fedora core 3

Tags: fedora

I have installed fedora core 3(heidelberg) on vmware. But I have problems accessing anything from the internet. How do I check if I'm connected to the internet?How do I utilize the internet connection of the host OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Precisely define what it means to have an "Internet connection". (Does it mean able to do DNS queries? Does it mean able to reach major web sites? Does it mean having an assigned IP address?)
2. Test for exactly the thing you defined in step 1. (Try some DNS queries. Try to retrieve some web pages. Check the IP address configuration.)

If you need a more specific answer, ask a more specific question.

Comment: I'm trying to access a webpage

Comment: Then try! If it works, you have an Internet connection. You can use `wget`.

Answer (score 2):

This shows I am able to connect to google.com (0% packet loss)

```
$ ping -c 3 google.com
PING google.com (74.125.226.226) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from lga15s29-in-f2.1e100.net (74.125.226.226): icmp_req=1 ttl=44 time=103 ms
64 bytes from lga15s29-in-f2.1e100.net (74.125.226.226): icmp_req=2 ttl=44 time=113 ms
64 bytes from lga15s29-in-f2.1e100.net (74.125.226.226): icmp_req=3 ttl=44 time=112 ms

--- google.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 103.412/109.808/113.653/4.553 ms
```

If you get 100% packet loss, then you're not connecting and you should also try running this

```
$ ping -c 3 74.125.226.226
```